# Upload images from Angular to SpringBoot

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I was trying for hours to send images from Angular to SpringBoot. Now I'm getting this error:

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request

Frontend(Angular) code looks like this:

```
  saveProduct(productSave: ProductSave, mainImg: File, imageList: File[]): Observable<any>
  {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const formListData = new FormData();

    formData.append('mainImg', mainImg, mainImg.name);

    imageList.forEach( img => formListData.append('imageList', img));

    return this.httpClient.post<ProductSave>(this.saveUrl, {productSave, mainImg, imageList});
  }
```

mainImg and imageList are images uploaded from user, and initialized like so:

```
mainImg = event.target.files[0];
imageList.push(event.target.files[0]);
```

My backend (SpringBoot) code looks like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public void saveProduct(@RequestBody ProductSave productSave, @RequestParam("mainImg")MultipartFile main, @RequestParam("imageList")MultipartFile[] multipartFiles)
    {
        System.out.println(productSave.getProduct().getName());
    }
```

I really don't have idea how to send those images, I was trying to look around stack but I faild.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the Spring Boot Controller method Arguments.

In multipart request, you can send the JSON Request body. Instead, you will have to send, key-value pairs.

So, you have 2 ways to do what you want to do -

1. Send JSON String and then deserialize it.

**Spring Boot API Sample :-**

```
    @PostMapping("/save")
        public String create(@RequestPart("file")MultipartFile multipartFile, @RequestPart("files") List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles, @RequestPart("jsonString") String jsonString) {
/** To convert string to POJO        
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper objectMapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
        
                 ProductSave productSave = this.objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,ProductSave.class); **/
                return jsonString;
       }
```

**HTML/Javascript Sample: -**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="file">
  <button onclick="submitData()">Submit Data</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitData() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      const fileField = document.querySelector('input[id="file"]');

      formData.append('jsonString', JSON.stringify({document: {data: 'value'}}));
      formData.append('file', fileField.files[0]);
      Array.from(fileField.files).forEach(f => formData.append('files', f));

      fetch('http://localhost:8080/save', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log('Success:', result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
    }
    
  </script>
</body>
```

And in front end:-

```
JSON.stringify(product);
```

2. Send Files as Byte Arrays, You don't need to use form data in frontend in this case.

You can convert file object to byte arrays in frontend using:-

```html
const fileToByteArray = async (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let fileByteArray = [];
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      reader.onloadend = (evt) => {
        if (evt.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
          const arrayBuffer = evt.target.result;
          const array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
          array.forEach((item) => fileByteArray.push(item));
        }
        resolve(fileByteArray);
      };
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Hi. I clouldn't run your solution one. And i'am to stupid to implement solution number two. So after hours I came up with most stupid solution. I insert all params to FormData.append(), and reciving it in SpringBoot one by one: ```@RequestParam("name")``` etc.

Comment: Checkout, if you can understand better, I have edited my answer with a sample html/javascript, java code for solution 1.

Answer (score 0):

in the `application.properties` try setting up the following -

```java
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1024KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1024KB
spring.http.multipart.enabled=false
```

Play around with the `max-file-size`.